# Odd 'GROUP BY' error in a sub-query while using Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-00979

A quick background -- I need to find the termination rates of cases that go through our company lab grouped by case type and month.  So far I came up with this:

```
SELECT BPI.TYPE,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE) MONTH,
       COUNT(*) termed_cases
  FROM CELL_SOURCE cs
  JOIN BASIC_PATHOLOGY_INFO bpi ON CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = BPI.CELL_SOURCE_ID
  JOIN RECENT_CELL_SOURCE_STATUS rcss ON CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = RCSS.CELL_SOURCE_ID
 WHERE type IS NOT NULL
  AND CS.RECEIVED_DATE > to_date('03/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY/')
  AND RCSS.STATUS like 'Term%'
GROUP BY BPI.TYPE, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE)
ORDER BY month, type
```

This finds all cases that have been termed, easy enough.  However, when I want to find the rate, I get a bit of a problem.  I tried using a sub-query to catch the total amount of cases per type regardless of it's status, as such:

```
COUNT(*)/(SELECT COUNT(*) 
            FROM CELL_SOURCE cs_1 
            JOIN BASIC_PATHOLOGY_INFO bpi_1 ON CS_1.CELL_SOURCE_ID = BPI_1.CELL_SOURCE_ID
          WHERE BPI_1.TYPE = BPI.TYPE 
            AND EXTRACT(month from CS_1.RECEIVED_DATE) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE)) termed_cases
```

However, this throws an `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` error, and highlights `BPI.TYPE` from the sub-query.

Anyone have any idea what my error could actually be?  Also, would an analytical function work better here than an aggregate function?

Comment: You need to group by BPI_1.TYPE inside the subquery

Comment: Is the "BPI.TYPE" in the select clause really supposed to be "BPI.TUMOR_TYPE" like you have in your group by?

Comment: Sorry, it's just type.  Tumor type is a different thing altogether -- a Freudian typo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you need two counts: a total for all cases in the month and a total for just the Termed cases.  The easiest way of doing this is to use a CASE() function to execute a conditional count, like this:

```
SELECT BPI.TYPE,
       EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE) MONTH,
       COUNT(*) all_cases,
       sum(case when RCSS.STATUS like 'Term%' then 1 else 0 end ) termed_cases
  FROM CELL_SOURCE cs
  JOIN BASIC_PATHOLOGY_INFO bpi ON CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = BPI.CELL_SOURCE_ID
  JOIN RECENT_CELL_SOURCE_STATUS rcss ON CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = RCSS.CELL_SOURCE_ID
 WHERE tumor_type IS NOT NULL
  AND CS.RECEIVED_DATE > to_date('03/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY/')
GROUP BY BPI.TUMOR_TYPE, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE)
ORDER BY month, tumor_type
```

Note that I have removed the LIKE filter from the WHERE clause.

Comment: The two counts are so one is divided by the other

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly the answer I needed.  Jeeze, even with a CS degree I'm still being baffled by this stuff.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select bpi.type , month, 
       termed_cases / 
   (select count(*) 
    from CELL_SOURCE cs_1 
    inner join BASIC_PATHOLOGY_INFO bpi_1 
        on CS_1.CELL_SOURCE_ID = BPI_1.CELL_SOURCE_ID
    where BPI_1.TUMOR_TYPE = BPI.TUMOR_TYPE 
    and extract(month from CS_1.RECEIVED_DATE) = extract(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE)
    )
from (
select BPI.TYPE,
extract(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE) MONTH,
count(*) termed_cases
from CELL_SOURCE cs
inner join BASIC_PATHOLOGY_INFO bpi
    on CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = BPI.CELL_SOURCE_ID
inner join RECENT_CELL_SOURCE_STATUS rcss
    on CS.CELL_SOURCE_ID = RCSS.CELL_SOURCE_ID
where tumor_type is not null
and CS.RECEIVED_DATE > to_date('03/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY/')
and RCSS.STATUS like 'Term%'
group by BPI.TYPE, extract(MONTH FROM CS.RECEIVED_DATE)
)
order by month, type
```